# Counting specific rows from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2012

I have to change my question.

I manage to create temp table with data about orders. I am not able to post a screenshot.

Columns are:

```
rownumber, account, orderposition, ordernnumber, opentime, closetime, modifaytime, symbol
```

Rows look like this

```
FIRST ROW
1, 12345, 1552723, 1576459, 2021-04-08 13:02:11,2021-04-08 13:02:11, 2021-04-08 13:02:11,'ELECTRICS' 

SECOND ROW
2, 12345, 1552725, 157611, 2021-04-08 13:02:16,2021-04-08 13:02:16, 2021-04-08 13:02:16,'ELECTRICS' 

THIRD ROW
..... almost like previous two

FOURTH ROW
4, 12345, 1558854, 1558854, 2021-04-08 13:04:01, 2000-01-01 00:00:00, 2021-04-08 13:04:01, 'ELECTRICS'
```

and so on.

When order is open closetime is equal to 2000-01-01., orderposition and ordernnumber are equal, when order is closed orderposition and ordernnumber are different, opentime is equal to closetime.

Open and close rows a mixed, row 5 is closed, row 6 is open etc ordered by modifytime.

I need to count rows(orders), but max open orders same day or open at the same time is 5

So if there is 5 orders from yesterday it's fault to open another order until at least one order from yesterday isn't closed and should have some output that will have data about accounts with more then 5 open orders

There are multiple accounts and symbols not only one

I'm new to T-SQL sql and tried everything I know, so I need help with this

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

"I need to count rows(orders), but max open orders same day or open at the same time is 5"

I am going to guess that you need to count the open orders?  You have not actually asked a question.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) [opencount] FROM tablename WHERE closetime = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: my problem isn't counting open orders or orders that are open and closed at the same day, problem is how to count if there are e.g. two previously opened orders are closed before then two new orders are open